# Cómo agregarle cuerpo al sms y enviarlo

Tags: javascript

Me interesa poder agregarle cuerpo al mensaje y también saber si se puede enviar automáticamente, ya que al dar click redirige a la aplicación de mensajes pero no lo envía...

```html
<a href="sms:+10000...">Enviar sms</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para agregarle cuerpo al mensaje se usa el siguiente codigo:

```
<a href="sms:+10000...?body=Escribe aqui lo que quieres enviar como texto">Enviar sms</a>
```